# App Store alert "This app not available in your country or region"

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

We developed iOS app in react native and have published it on app store with all countries / regions selected (which is by default selected) from Pricing and availability section. Still showing the alert "This app not available in your country or region".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you attach images or other explanations to better understand? Logically, the app must be available everywhere. Do you have specific elements in your app that could cause Apple to reject the app?

Comment: Hey, I have submitted second version on App console. And then it's enabled.